# Win32: Is it possible to show the window but to hide it from taskbar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

If I have an win32 application with several windows, is it possible to show a window but hide the window icon in the taskbar?

I have tried creating the window with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW and WS_EX_APPWINDOW.

Answer (score 18):

You have a few options:

1. Tool windows do not have taskbar buttons. Create a tool window by including the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended window style.
2. Owned windows without the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style do not have taskbar buttons.
3. Hidden windows do not have taskbar buttons.

Option 1 is simple enough. If you don't want to use a tool window, use a combination of 2 and 3. Create a hidden unowned window that is the owner of your main window.